# Qual a forma correta de se declarar um WebMethod asmx em C# para receber requisições POST com parâmetros?

Tags: c#, web-service, jquery-plugins, asmx

Estou tentando montar um processo de upload de arquivos para um web service feito em ***c#*** ***.asmx***, mas não estou conseguindo manipular o envio de parâmetros através do método ***POST***.

Este é o webMethod que criei:

```cs
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("UserAuthentication")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void UploadFiles(string token)
{
    CheckHeader();
    if (!(Context.Request.Files.Count > 0))
        return;
    var path = (UserAuthentication.Usuario.Login + token).GetHashCode();
    var directory = DiretorioPublicacaoArquivos();

    foreach (string fileItem in Context.Request.Files.AllKeys) {
        var file = Context.Request.Files[fileItem];

        if (Strings.IsPopulated(file.FileName)) {
            var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory + @"\temp\" + path+ @"\");
            if (!dirInfo.Exists)
                dirInfo.Create();

            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(dirInfo.FullName + file.FileName);
            if (fileInfo.Exists)
                fileInfo.Delete();

            file.SaveAs(fileInfo.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

O parâmetro *`token`* é um identificador que receberei do *client* para poder criar um diretório temporário onde será armazenado os arquivos conforme os for recebendo.

Então, no *client*, usando o **[jquery.uploadfile](https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file)**, monto o formulário para upload dos arquivos:

```html
<div id="upload">Selecionar Arquivos</div>
```

```js
$("#upload").uploadFile({
    url: "/Services/PublicacaoService.asmx/UploadFiles",
    method: "post",
    fileName: "myfile",
    dynamicFormData: function () {
        var data = { token: "123 testando" };
        return data;
    },
    multiple: true,
});
```

De acordo com a documentação do plugin, posso utilizar tanto o método `dynamicFormData` como o atributo **[`formData`](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data)**, passando meu parâmetro diretamente para ele.

Exemplo:

```js
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    formData: {example: 'test'}
});
```

Já tentei de ambas as formas, mas não consigo enviar arquivos quando preciso passar um parâmetro para o webMethod. O que ocorre é que os arquivos anexados logo retornam um ***Internal Server Error***.

Porém, basta tirar o parâmetro do cabeçalho do *webMethod* e já consigo fazer com que o *break-point*, adicionado dentro do *webMethod* para ***debug***, seja ativado.

```cs
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("UserAuthentication")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void UploadFiles() // <-- sem o parâmetro
{ 
    ... 
}
```

Inlusive, manipulando para jogar em outra pasta que não dependa do *token*, funciona. Claro que não é assim que preciso, é somente para testes.

**Como resolver isso?**
**Qual a forma correta de declarar o WebMethod para receber as requisições pelo método POST e com parâmetros?**

Comment: Nunca tentei fazer isso, mas acho que é uma mistura [dessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143630/upload-file-through-c-sharp-using-json-request-and-restsharp) com [esta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443392/how-do-i-pass-a-file-into-a-web-method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com seu método não tinha nada de errado.
Tanto que se você testar com :

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $.ajax(
              {
                   url: "/Services/PublicacaoService.asmx/UploadFiles",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                   dataType: "json",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: "{token:'test'}"
               });
        });
    </script>
```

Verá que seu método vai parar no seu break point.

Para esse plugin, sugiro que você mude seu método UploadFiles para o seguinte :

```
public void UploadFiles()
{
    var token = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("token");
    CheckHeader();
    if (!(Context.Request.Files.Count > 0))
    //Continuação do seu código
}
```

No plugin quando você usa `dynamicFormData` o 'token' é adicionado no form, e então você consegue recuperar no lado do servidor usando HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("token");

O Internal Server Error que você recebia provavelmente era esse erro :

> System.InvalidOperationException: Formato de solicitação
>   inválido: multipart/form-data; boundary=----blahblahblah